# Could not get unknown property 'fabricToolsVersion' for root project 'quickblox-android-sdk-master' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, quickblox

i am getting this error

> Error:(7, 0) Could not get unknown property 'fabricToolsVersion' for root project 'quickblox-android-sdk-master' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>   Open File

i recently migrated from android 2.3.3 to 3.0.1 the project was working fine. After migrating i got different errors after solving one i get a new error.

can anyone tell me how can i fix this?

here i  my gradle.build

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

    dependencies {
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:$rootProject.fabricToolsVersion"
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion
    flavorDimensions rootProject.dimensionDefault

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.quickblox.sample.chat"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.versionName
    }

    productFlavors {
        speedDev {
            dimension rootProject.dimensionDefault
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        dev {
            dimension rootProject.dimensionDefault
            minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled false
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("../cert/debug.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


}


dependencies {
    implementation (project(":sample-core"))

    implementation ("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:$rootProject.qbSdkVersion")
    implementation("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:$rootProject.qbSdkVersion")

    implementation "com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:$rootProject.swipyVersion@aar"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${rootProject.glideVersion}"
    implementation (name: 'sticky-list-headers', ext: 'aar')
}

apply from: "../artifacts.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: show your `gradle.build`

Comment: i edited the post and added build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

in string:

`classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:$rootProject.fabricToolsVersion"`

of your `rootProject/build.gradle` file, replace  `$rootProject.fabricToolsVersion`

with

`${rootProject.fabricToolsVersion}` or `1.25.1`.

That should result in:

`classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:${rootProject.fabricToolsVersion}"`

or `classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1"`.

Or you could create an external property by adding to rootProject/build.gradle parameter `ext.fabricToolsVersion = '1.25.1'`